# bq Aquaris E4.5 mobile internet problem

Tags: ubuntu-touch, smartphone

Mobile internet connection unstable and intermittent, most of the time not connected. WiFi works fine. The following was checked/confirmed:

- SIM card works fine on another phone
- tried both SIM slots, the same issue in both
- checked network status in the area, all mobile services normal

The mobile provider's support recommends deleting default APN setting and inputting custom APN but in this phone the system seems to automatically revert to the default setting, and I do not see an option for deleting the default APN or changing it.

Comment: This could be one of a number of bugs around networking which we're fixing. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/?field..searchtext=&field.tag=connectivity

Answer (score 0):

In "System parameters > Mobile Phone > Operator > Name of the access point" or equivalent, check that your internet access point is enabled.